# Can I pause a multiplayer game?

Tags: borderlands-2

Are multiplayer (co-op) Borderlands 2 games pausable? I plan on buying the game to play with a friend but the ability to pause is important for us, so I want to verify that first.

Comment: I've never played Borderlands, but since pausing with a group of people would have to pause everyone else in the group, I think not.

Comment: As far as I know, the pause menu behaves the same as Minecraft when in Multiplayer mode: **No pausing**.

Comment: Come to think of it, does Borderlands 2 have a console of somesort? (Like in TF2) maybe you can work something out from there. Alternatively, suspending the whole borderlands program achieves the same thing, but may cause crashes... And only if you're the host.

Comment: As aytinothy said, I don't believe you can pause online games, but I believe local games are a different story. Do you plan on playing online or locally on the same system?

Comment: @Leon7C online multiplayer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you cannot pause Borderlands 2 if you play multiplayer.

If this is an issue for you, I would suggest that this shouldn't keep you from playing this amazing game.

There are areas that enemies spawn and once killed, they take a long time to respawn. You don't have to go all the way back into a safe town to pause and look at items or whatever.

Comment: Even if you have a situation that might require you to walk away from the game immediately, without even time to find cover first, I agree with Chase that this shouldn't prevent you enjoying the game.  The penalty for death is remarkably light (a small percentage of your on-hand cash), respawn zones are almost always safe, and a decent team can function fine missing a member for a while.  You might even come to appreciate the Badass Ranks you earn reviving your ally while he's AFK. I sometimes get distracted with my team of three and they don't seem to suffer for it when I'm a minute behind.

Comment: Yes, agreed. Dying in Borderlands is often funny rather than frustrating. Pausing and taking your time is okay since an entire area is loaded for everyone at once. And the game isn't really that hard if you play on normal, especially with multiple people.

Comment: @gatherer818 thank you for your comment; that's really encouraging.

Answer (score 2):

**Playing online, Borderlands does not give you the ability to pause.** This is more an inherent requirement for online play. You should expect the same for any game being played over the internet.

That said, **the penalty for dieing should not discourage you** from taking a toilet break, and unless you right in the thick of things or drastically unequal in level, **your friend should have no problem covering you** while you grab a drink/go to the toilet/have a cigarette.

That said, **if you are playing split screen, you can pause the game**, no worries.

Answer (score 0):

**Look at the ground** and you should be fine, as long as you didn't already aggro them. Re-spawned or nearby enemies usually don't engage you, if you **don't move or look at them**.